# How to use AWS-Fargate as a python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I want to use AWS-Fargate as a data PreProcessor in a ML pipe.

I deployed Docker Image containing my python script within AWS-ECR.

I also created a task with this image.

My questions are :

1. Which cluster should i use, i don't understand well the concept of cluster.
2. How to deploy in the pipe (the best should be triger by s3 event and execute as `docker run`)

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cluster to use is [Networking only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create_cluster.html):

   > With this option, you can launch a cluster with a new VPC to use for **Fargate tasks**.
2. The CICD pipeline for automated deployment of your Docker images to your ECS service could be constructed using **CodePipeline**. The good start towards it is the following tutorial:

   . [Tutorial: Continuous Deployment with CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html) for ECS